# highcharts area range date format

Tags: php, json, ajax, highcharts

I'm confused a little bit. I would like to use `Highcharts` area range graph in my projects and this example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/arearange/)
But i have my own simple `json` response and problem is date format my data array looks like this:

```
[[2016-10-24,22.0,25.0],[2016-10-25,23.0,25.0],[2016-10-26,24.0,25.0]]
```

and it not work because date format in original query looks like this: [source](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=range.json&callback=?)
My question is how to make it work with date from sql server do i need to convert into another format or what?

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts accepts datetime type only as timestamp in miliseconds so you have to parse it to the valid format to make a chart work.

```
data: [
    [new Date("2016-10-24").getTime(), 22.0, 25.0],
    [new Date("2016-10-25").getTime(), 23.0, 25.0],
    [new Date("2016-10-26").getTime(), 24.0, 25.0]
  ]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/n5dh4607/

Comment: how to convert sql datetime  format in sql serverinto utc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `strtotime` function, which gives you epoch time in seconds, and multiply the result by 1,000 to get the milliseconds that are required.

Reference:

- http://www.epochconverter.com/
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php